# Check if a specific date is between two dates using between gives incorrect result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple table called `Leave` with the following table structure and data:

[image]

I am executing the following query on this table:

```
 select  id 
 from Leave 
 where
 employee_id = 14 
 and (CAST(Convert(date,GETDATE(),102) as datetime) between
 CAST(Convert(date,'2021-08-10 00:00:00.000',102) as datetime) and 
 CAST(Convert(date,'2021-08-14 00:00:00.000',102) as datetime)  )
 and approved_by IS NOT NULL
```

I am getting this:
1038
1039

I am expecting the result to be the following:
1038

The reason I am expecting this result is that the current date that is `2021-08-11 00:00:00.000` is in between 1038's start_date and end_date and not between 1039's.

Comment: None of your logic references `start_date` or `end_date`, so why would you expect those columns to affect your result at all?

Comment: Do **not**, **never**, **never ever** post images of tables. Post the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements as **text**.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am simulating those cols values by hard coding date values. Please see the query it is getting id of the row where a date lies between the date range and 1039's id is being fetched while its start_date and end_date does not lie in the range specified in the query

Comment: I agree with @Damien_The_Unbeliever. You need to first select id, getdate(), start_date, end_date as `select  id, getdate(), start_date, end_date from Leave  where employee_id = 14 and approved_by IS NOT NULL`. With this, you will know what column is not you expected.

Comment: @MuhammadAli - but that means that you're hard coding as if *every* row has those same values, so there's no distinction between the two rows you're getting.

Comment: Does it work if you use: `WHERE Employee_id = 14 AND start_date <= GETDATE() AND end_date > GETDATE() AND approved_by IS NOT NULL`? I think your conversion of `GETDATE()` to a date is unnecessary, especially with an inclusive date range (i.e. with `BETWEEN`) as it means that something that ended today at midnight would still get picked up despite ending in the past. Since `CONVERT(DATE, '2021-08-11 13:21') <= '2021-08-11 00:00')` is true.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, I see the issue now, thank you, sir. New to SQL so learning

Comment: @GarethD yes sir it works that way, I understand the issue now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not querying `start_date` and `end_date`, so your query is equivilent to

```
 select  id 
 from Leave 
 where
 employee_id = 14 
 and approved_by IS NOT NULL
```

when run an any date between the two literal dates in your query.  Should be something like:

```
 select  id 
 from Leave 
 where
 employee_id = 14 
 and cast(getdate() as date) between
 CAST(start_date as date) and 
 CAST(end_date as date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have a timezone issue.  Or some arcane problem with `convert(date, getdate(), 102)` -- no format is needed when converting from a `datetime` to a `date`.

In the meantime, your query can be much simplified:

```
select id 
from Leave 
where employee_id = 14 and
      approved_by is not null and
      convert(date, getdate()) between '2021-08-10' and '2021-08-14';
```

Or, if you prefer SQL Server's unambiguous date formats:

```
select id 
from Leave 
where employee_id = 14 and
      approved_by is not null and
      convert(date, getdate()) between '20210810' and '20210814';
```

Comment: I am executing the query on local SSMS on local DB, I don't think there can be a timezone issue? I copied your first query, executed it but still getting same result(1038 and 1039)

Comment: I don't see how that could be happening with your sample data.